# Why was http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182864/arduino-relay-shield migrated?

Tags: discussion

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182864/arduino-relay-shield was migrated to the Arduino Beta stack. Aside from it having NOTHING to do with Arduinos from the meat of the question (will this new design work?), it seems it was blindly migrated. Was this a request by OP or what?

As no response is forthcoming, it's obvious that one Mod has decided that Arduino questions are off topic, despite established community policy that they are on topic, and that questions are not supposed to be migrated to beta stacks against standard Stack Exchange policy as well. He will typically snipe any question he feels is ""off-topic"" to be migrated out within minutes of it being posted. This is unacceptable. Moderators are not supposed to dictate policy, or ignore the community, they are supposed to enforce what the community decided on.

[image]

Comment: Re http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/migration-guidelines-re-arduinos?rq=1 and http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/regarding-question-migrated-to-arduino-s-e?rq=1 and http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/arduino-question-migration?rq=1 and http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5159/stop-migrating-arduino-questions-if-theres-a-significant-portion-of-electronics?rq=1

Comment: Also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/182107/revisions was migrated out without any good reason.

Comment: Possibly http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/179549/revisions as well...

Comment: And http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/178619/revisions

Comment: What is with all the single sided migrations to Arduino Stack?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

These issues don't seem to get resolved here. The best would be to collect some recent posts that were migrated incorrectly and write the SE, Inc. team using the 'contact us' link at the bottom of every page.

As a side note, I just came across [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electrical-engineering) today (emphasis mine):

> ## Electrical Engineering
>
> Launched Q&A site for launched Q&A site for electronics hardware hacking enthusiasts - topics that include electronics, physical computing, ***and even those working with an Arduino***.

Comment: Worst of all, these questions are just single handedly being closed as off topic, then migrated out within **minutes** of posting. Not even enough time for the community to collectively ignore it.

Comment: Haven't you guys figured out that the community as a whole is either indifferent, or agrees with the migrations? There are very few people that agree with you. Get over it.

Comment: Because everybody else has been bullied away.

Comment: @Passerby just interested - did you write the team already about this? And, did you get a reply? [As I wrote](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5327/17592) I never received a reply.

Comment: Yep, no reply, on multiple issues

Comment: Hmm. Well, let's hope that's because they're discussing things internally.

Comment: About as likely as them being reasonable adults and answering truthfully here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not real interested in reviewing every decision, but I can provide some rough numbers for discussion.

There have been about 30 migrations to Arduino since July 1, and about 120 Arduino tagged questions that stayed over that same time period.  One in 5 is getting migrated.

Comment: 20% migrated for no reason other than they simply mention arduino. That's horrible.

Comment: No, 20% migrated because someone thought they were more appropriate for that group, possibly after some discussion with those mods.  As I've suggested before, most were probably appropriate, and the few border cases, or even plain outright misses, just don't seem to get me worked up.

Comment: Yet migrations to betas arn't allowed, and policy was just refreshed recently that arduino questions shouldnt be migrated http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/migration-guidelines-re-arduinos?rq=1

Comment: @Passerby, I think the mods and community have seen fit to move past that particular decision.  Certainly, there has been active discussion between the community, our mods, and the arduino.se mods, both in our meta and behind the scenes between then and now.

Comment: @Passerby FWIW, those migration numbers were probably must higher before you and Camil started advocating for these questions.  You've opened dialogue between the mods of the two stacks, and clearly changed behavior.  You've asked the community to move, and the community moved significantly.

Comment: the issue is that these questions arn't being migrated by community votes. They arn't lingering without answers here. They arn't being downvoted. It be a different thing if they were neglected.

Comment: @Passerby, the migration options for user based migration absolutely 100% unequivocally suck.  There is NO way for this community to vote to migrate to arduino.se.

Comment: Custom close message, or simply comment and/or upvote a comment stating it.

Comment: @Passerby, that still doesn't give you a community vote mechanism to migrate, and frankly if it requires a keyboard its too much work.  I prefer the mods to take the action they see fit until real migration options are in place.

Comment: Apart from the issues Passerby already mentioned, there is another issue playing here which is annoying enough for me to stay away from this site as much as possible. It is that the moderator handling these migrations doesn't respond to queries like this. He has taken up the strategy of "Migrate and run".

Comment: @CamilStaps Then perhaps that would make a better question instead of a third or fourth go around of the same topic (though I feel the topic has been adequately addressed to the satisfaction of many)

Comment: Indeed, I have brought that to attention already several times, for example in the comments on [this question](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5159/17592). But the moderator in question doesn't show any effort to 'be nicer', I'm too tired to find the right word. **You may disagree with our requests. But how can you disagree with the request that Meta questions are answered properly?** It could be your question. Something with protecting minorities. Ah, well.

Comment: @CamilStaps -  it seems to me the only answer you'll find acceptable is "I'm sorry, we'll moderate exactly the way you want."  If this isn't the case, why don't you tell us all what you'd like the mods to say that will make this go away.  Personally, I think this has been answered repeatedly, with the latest go around establishing direct communication between two stacks mods -  you just don't care for the result.

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5327/17592 here you are. But really it is for the biggest part a repetition and collection of what I have been saying before. I thank you for your request though - you are one of the only ones who, while disagreeing, keeps respectful conversation in mind. You are one of the most constructive people participating in this discussion, to me at least.